# Finding the Factorial of range between 1 to N

Tags: c, algorithm, loops, factorial

trying to write a program that would find the factorial of range of numbers starting from 1 to N,N being the final Number to find the factorial for, i have written a  non-recursive  program.it only works for integers 1 and 2 in the loop, i'm not sure how to fix it because the logic seems fine,also i'm somewhat still a beginner,so i know i'm probably missing something that's obvious,but in any case  here's the code :

```
 #include<stdio.h>



int main() {
    
    int firstnumber;
    int finalnumber;

printf("this is a program to calculate the factorial of numbers between 1 to N\n"); 


printf("please enter the final number : ");

 
scanf("%d",&finalnumber);

int i;
int factorial=1;


for (firstnumber=1;firstnumber<=finalnumber;firstnumber++) {
    printf("the factorial of %d is : ",firstnumber);
 
 
    for (i=1;i<=firstnumber;i++) {
        factorial=factorial*i;
    }

    printf("%d \n ",factorial);
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aside: I suggest you work with `unsigned long long` or with `uint64_t` to get a more useful working range. The limit with 32-bit `int` is 12! before overflow.

Comment: @WeatherVane and the limit with `uint64_t` is 20!

Comment: Why is there no feedback on the answers given? Were they really that bad?

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize `factorial` before each calculation.

```
int i;
// delete this
//int factorial=1;


for (firstnumber=1;firstnumber<=finalnumber;firstnumber++) {
    printf("the factorial of %d is : ",firstnumber);

    // move the declaration here
    int factorial=1;

    for (i=1;i<=firstnumber;i++) {
        factorial=factorial*i;
    }

    printf("%d \n ",factorial);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your two loops are redundant: you can calculate factorial for `number` from factorial of `number - 1`

This is the programme with one loop only. Complexity O(N).

Pay attention that you will get overflow rapidly by using `int`.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main() {
    
    int number;
    int finalnumber;

    printf("this is a program to calculate the factorial of numbers between 1 to N\n"); 

    printf("please enter the final number : ");

    scanf("%d",&finalnumber);

    int factorial = 1;

    for (number=1; number<=finalnumber; number++) {
        printf("the factorial of %d is : ",number);
        factorial *= number;
        printf("%d \n",factorial);
    }

    return 0;
}
```